# Firebase authentication for Sinatra (Ruby) web app

Tags: ruby, firebase, sinatra, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use Firebase for authentication of a Sinatra app in much the same way that I can use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails), and if so, how? The samples from Firebase all seem to assume single-page applications talking to a backend using JWT. Mine would be a traditional, fully server-side-rendered app.